# Change a default annotation value for all usages

Tags: java, spring-boot, reflection, annotations, micrometer

The `@Timed` annotation in Spring Boot (part of Micrometer) has several fields. One of these is:

```
double[] percentiles() default {};
```

I would like to set this value **once across the entire codebase** to a different array, say:

```
new double[] { 0.0, 50.0 };
```

This is achievable in one of two ways that I know of:

1. Setting the field on every instance:

   ```
   @Timed(percentiles = new double[] { 0.0, 50.0 })
   ```
2. Using `@AliasFor` or meta-annotations to create a different annotation with the desired value.

I have also come across the [AnnotationUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationUtils.html) class, but cannot see how to achieve my goal.

What is the standard way of doing this in Spring Boot? If it cannot be done in Spring Boot, how does one do it with the JDK's own reflection capabilities?

Comment: the standard way of doing this is "NOT". that default value is by design, it's because they want that to be the default value

Comment: @Stultuske A default is there to be changed. Having no percentiles in your statistics is completely useless. The value is designed to be overriden.

Comment: yes, but not for all possible instances, that's when it stops being a default. The point of a default is to be the fallback value unless another value is chosen by the implementation

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own meta-annotation with `@Timed`. See for more details: https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/145

Comment: That was my option 2 - I'll edit my question to make it clear I was referring to meta-annotations. I was looking for a way to do it without the use of a new annotation, but I'll definitely consider this if it's not possible. Thank you!

Comment: AFAIK this is a general approach to achieve the goal you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to configure a set of percentiles for all histograms generated throughout your application you can use a `MeterFilter`.

Micrometer Docs: https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_configuring_distribution_statistics

In your spring boot project you would create the meter filter as a bean ie.

```
    @Bean
    public MeterFilter meterFilter() {
        return new MeterFilter() {
            @Override
            public DistributionStatisticConfig configure(Meter.Id id, DistributionStatisticConfig config) {
                return DistributionStatisticConfig.builder()
                        .percentiles(0.5, 0.75, 0.95, 0.98, 0.99)
                        .percentilesHistogram(true)
                        .build()
                        .merge(config);
            }
        };
    }
```